# Image gallery with codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, image-gallery

I have some images uploaded in a folder on my server, and their paths are stored
in a table in my database. Whats the best way to display this images on the browser(as a gallery)?

Should I use jQuery or maybe CodeIgniter could do the job?

Comment: How exactly would "jqery" connect to your database?

Comment: Not really connect to my db but do the display and move around images... sorry if the question sounds stupid...

Comment: for what purpose paths were saved in the database?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel it is supposed to be a good practice not to store images straight in the database but storing them somewhere in your server and just save paths in a table...

Comment: so, you have no reasons to do that? well, do not use a database then. Just read filenames from the folder and display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to agree that you're probably a little bit confused. There are two components that have to happen here.

1. You'll need server-side code (*e.g.* plain PHP or PHP + CodeIgniter Framework) to pull the information from your database and render some HTML / JavaScript to present that content to the user.
2. You'll need client-side code to turn your marked-up HTML into some kind of gallery, assuming you want it "active".

There are almost an infinite number of ways to perform #1, and they are totally dependent on your database configuration, server, etc. Using CodeIgniter with Active Record, and assuming that you already have an active database connection, the PHP would look something like this:

```
<?php
    $photos = $this->db->get('photo_table'); // Retrieve photos from DB
    $photos = $photos->result_array();

    foreach($photos as $photo) {
        echo '<img src="' . $photo['url'] . '" alt="' . $photo['alt'] . '" />';
    }
?>
```

Number two is most easily handled by using something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) + [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/). There are literally hundreds of gallery/slideshow/photo plugins for jQuery. If you're interested in looking around, there are a bunch [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/).

Answer (score 0):

Just a very simple query on the table will do, I think your getting confused as to what jquery and codeigniter do! For something like this just use some simple PHP:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<img src="'.$row['file_path'].'" alt="" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks fire...I'm probably a bit confused...can you suggest a good way to navigate through the images?